# Handling xor with different key sizes and endianess

Tags: c, endianness, xor, bitwise-xor

I am playing around with xor decoding via a small C file, and am running into issues with endianness ...I am a bit stuck on how to work around them.  This is really the first time I've played this deeply with bitwise operations in C.

If I use a one-byte xor key and pick up several xor-encoded values into a uint8_t pointer, my basic code works fine.  Walk each byte, xor it against the key, and store the result in a decoded byte array/buffer and then print it back to the console.

However, if I try a two-byte xor key, then endianness starts to get in the way.  I currently stick the key into a uint32_t, because I don't plan on dealing with xor keys greater than 32bits.  On a little-endian system, a xor key of `0xc39f` gets stored as `0x9fc3`.  The bytes to be decoded are big-endian if I play them back one byte at a time, but they too, get flipped to little-endian if I try to play them back two-bytes at a time (same size as the xor key).

I am tempted to `#include <byteswap.h>` and then call `bswap_32()`.  But while this will work on little endian, it might have the opposite effect on big-endian.  I assume then I'd need ugly #ifdef's to only use `bswap_32()` for little-endian archs.  I figure, there has got to be a more portable way for this to work.

Random sample string:

```
g   e   n   e   r   a   t   e
67  65  6e  65  72  61  74  65

Xor 0xc39f

a4  fa  ad  fa  b1  fe  b7  fa
```

If I play back the xor-encoded buffer with two-byte (uint16_t) pointers, I get this (via a basic printf):

```
0xfaa4 0xfaad 0xfeb1 0xfab7
```

And with four-byte pointers (uint32_t):

```
0xfaadfaa4 0xfab7feb1
```

I would expect for the above, to get instead for two-byte pointers:

```
0xa4fa 0xadfa 0xb1fe 0xb7fa
```

And four-byte pointers:

```
0xa4faadfa 0xb1feb7fa
```

Thoughts?

**Edit:** Any takers?  Current answers aren't adequate to my needs.

Comment: Code is a bit of a mess and really just hackish attempts at try to use a `switch` statement to see if I am dealing with 1, 2, or 4 byte Xor keys, and then loop appropriately in each `case` block.  The bits for `case 2` and `case 4` are actually just `printf()` calls to dump the bytes and see how endianness affects them.  So there really isn't much worth posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overthinking this—just treat your xor key as an endianless binary blob, and convert it to a native `uint32_t` for performance:

```
void xor_encrypt_slow(uint8_t *data, size_t len, uint8_t key[4])
{
    // key is a 4-byte xor key
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
        data[i] ^= key[i % 4];
}

void xor_encrypt_fast(uint8_t *data, size_t len, uint8_t key[4])
{
    // Convert key to a 32-bit value
    uint32_t key32 = *(uint32_t *)key;

    // This assumes that data is aligned on a 4-byte boundary; if not, adjust
    // accordingly
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i + 3 < len; i += 4)
        ((uint32_t *)data)[i] ^= key32;
    // Handle the remainder, if len is not a multiple of 4
    for( ; i < len; i++)
        data[i] ^= key[i % 4];
}
```

Comment: The key is already stored in a uint32_t, but not as a pointer.  My buffer with the encoded values is different than what will hold the decoded values.  The decoded buffer will be a uint8_t array.  By using a xor key as a straight uint32_t, even if it is just one byte, how is this making sure that every byte gets xor'ed by just the one byte if you are doing it 4 bytes at a time (yell if I am wrong on this)?

Comment: I am not satisfied with this answer.  But, no one else has contributed, so as the *most complete* answer, even if it does not satisfy my question, it wins.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `htonl()` macro, which is designed exactly for this purpose.  It stands for "hex to network long" and is defined to swap (or not swap) bytes to make the resulting values big-endian, as required before transmitting them over the network.